# SQL Server Insert Into Pivoted View

Tags: sql-server, view, insert, pivot

Let's say I have a table testpivot that looks like this, with district and metric a unique key:

| id | district | metric | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | work | 40 |
| 2 | a | hours | 80 |
| 3 | b | work | 50 |
| 4 | b | hours | 85 |

I create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW vpivot
AS

SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT district, metric, value
    FROM testpivot
)t
PIVOT(SUM(value) for metric IN(work,hours)) as p
```

So querying from the view looks like this:

| district | work | hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 40 | 80 |
| b | 50 | 85 |

Is there a way to make an insert query like this work:

```
  INSERT INTO vpivot SELECT 'c',20,80
```

Answer (score 0):

Select * from vpivot
UNION
SELECT 'c',20,80

Comment: to clarify, I'm trying to insert data into the table